# F# graph library (ocamlgraph like)

Tags: f#, ocaml

I'm writing a program in ocaml using ocamlgraph and wondering if I am to port it to F# what are my options ? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[QuickGraph](http://www.codeplex.com/quickgraph) is one of the most complete graph libraries for .Net

Answer (score 5):

OCamlGraph is a beautiful example of a higher-order module system really paying off. F# cannot express this so a translation will not only be difficult to do at all but the result will be inherently far more cumbersome to use. Your best bet is to reuse some existing graph library for .NET and you'll probably have to settle for far less abstraction.

Answer (score -1):

There is [GLEE](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/f1303e46-965f-401a-87c3-34e1331d32c5/default.aspx) by Microsoft Research (it's an early version of Microsoft Automatic Graph Layout ). GLEE is free to download (MSAG must be purchased). I'm have used GLEE for large enough graphs. It's fast and easy to use.

Comment: The question is about a library called ocamlgraph written in the OCaml programming language that implements a wide variety of graph algorithms neatly abstracted over graph representations (both mutable and immutable). You answer is about a graph *visualization* library, which is a completely different kettle of fish.